# cant open thraed in kernel mod

Tags: c++, c, windows-kernel

i developing kernel mod driver and i try to open thread with access with NtOpenThread

i start with ZwQuerySystemInformation with flag SystemProcessInformation
to run on all the runing process with this struct PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION

i found the process that i look for
i get the pointer to the SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION
and now i have all the running threads in the process

now i need to get the THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION from NtQueryInformationThread
for this function i need to open thread with full access i try this code but no success

```
SYSTEM_THREAD_INFORMATION* st = spi->Threads;

HANDLE hThread;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES   ObjectAttributes;
InitializeObjectAttributes(&ObjectAttributes, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
NTSTATUS res = NtOpenThread(&hThread, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, &ObjectAttributes, &st->ClientId);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(res)) {
    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}

THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATIO info = { 0 }; 
durum = NtQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadBasicInformation, &info, sizeof(PTHREAD_BASIC_INFORMATIO), NULL);

DbgPrintEx(0, 0, "info->TebBaseAddress: %#010x", info.TebBaseAddress);

if (!info.TebBaseAddress > 0) {
    return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
}
```

but the code never pass the NtOpenThread. i print the NTSTATUS res and i get 0xC0000005 and its mean
STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION
whyyy what worng??

i try to run this code on c++ exe and its work ok

```
DWORD pid = te.th32OwnerProcessID;//process id
DWORD tid = te.th32ThreadID;//thread id
HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pid);
if (hProcess == NULL)
{
    int error = GetLastError();
    cout << "OpenProcess error: " << error << endl;
}
HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, false, tid);
if (hThread == NULL)
{
    int error = GetLastError();
    cout << "OpenThread error: " << error << endl;
}

HMODULE h = LoadLibrary(L"ntdll.dll");
fpNtQueryInformationThread NtQueryInformationThread = (fpNtQueryInformationThread)GetProcAddress(h, "NtQueryInformationThread");

THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION info = { 0 };
NTSTATUS ret = NtQueryInformationThread(hThread, ThreadBasicInformation, &info, sizeof(THREAD_BASIC_INFORMATION), NULL);

printf("info->TebBaseAddress: %#010x\n", info.TebBaseAddress);
printf("info->UniqueProcess: %d\n", info.ClientId.UniqueProcess);
printf("info->UniqueThread: %d\n", info.ClientId.UniqueThread);
NT_TIB tib = { 0 };
if (!ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, info.TebBaseAddress, &tib, sizeof(NT_TIB), nullptr))
{
    int error = GetLastError();
    cout << "ReadProcessMemory error: " << error << endl;
}

printf("StackLimit: %#010x to StackBase: %#010x \n", tib.StackBase, tib.StackLimit);
```

Comment: i guess you call this with previous mode == *UserMode* (inside handle some request from user mode). you need use *ZwOpenThread*

Comment: yhaaaaa its work.!